# Why is an Obj-C question about -dealloc not a real question?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, closed-questions, not-a-real-question

Someone just asked [a question about how -dealloc gets called](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7093136/643383). The question was closed without comment shortly after it was posted, despite being fairly clear and having a definite answer. I'd agree that its' a pretty basic question that could easily be answered by consulting the appropriate Objective-C language reference, but that seems like grounds for a downvote rather than closing as 'not a real question'.

Is this a case of abusing "not a real question"?

Comment: Even with your edits, the question still shows no research effort at all, and if posted like that might still be closed.

Comment: Nice job editing that question.  As Cody pointed out, I couldn't make heads or tails of it as originally written, but I think you've done a great job in reshaping it into a coherent question.  It got reopened, so I think you've succeeded here.

Answer (score 13):

You're focusing on the *topic* of the question (an Objective-C question about `-dealloc`), which is almost certainly **not** why the question was closed as "not a real question". Focus instead on the overall quality of the *question itself*, including the way in which it is asked.

Note that [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093136/who-call-dealloc-method-and-when-in-objective-c) looked like this when it was closed:

> #### Who call dealloc method ?? and when?? in objective c
>
> When We Create a new custom class in objective c Who call dealloc method ?? and when?? in objective c.

Really? You think this is a real question? It doesn't make much sense to me and looks like a complete abomination. I don't really understand how this grammatically-nonsensical one-liner even made it through our automatic filter designed specifically to keep out such low-quality questions. If this is a case of anything, it's a case of abusing the "Ask Question" feature.

If you think that there is possibly a real question in there somewhere, then it is *your* job to edit the question and extract the real question part that you see. Neither me nor the 5 close voters see it.
<sup>(When you edit, make sure to add the phrase `in objective c` 6 or 8 more times, just to be super-duper clear.)</sup>

Once you've done that, *then* you should flag the post for moderator attention to get it re-opened or bring the issue here to Meta, hoping to elicit the votes of 4 more community members.

Comment: Somebody didn't have their coffee this morning

Comment: @James: Uh, why do you say that?

Comment: @James: possible, but if that's the result, then I wholeheartedly approve occasional coffeelessness ;-)

Comment: @Cody Gray It's a pretty good chewing out for 830 in the morning

Comment: @James: I don't see it that way. Perhaps I'm "chewing out" the person who asked the original question, but (s)he isn't here. And I don't really understand why you think that the question in question deserves a free pass. (I haven't even gone to sleep yet, so it's not a coffee or early morning issue. I'm always this sunshine-y.)

Comment: @CodyGray, I'm sure you're right, and I should have edited the question before I posted here. Nevertheless, even in its original ramshackle form, I think the intent of the question was pretty easy to discern. Anyway, I've edited now and expect that the question is now "real"; I hope you'll consider voting to reopen.

Comment: @Cody Gray I never said the question deserves a free pass, I would have voted to close as well.  The point I'm making is that the answer you provided to this question is abrasive to the point of making me question whether or not you had enough coffee.

Comment: @James: Where is the abrasive part?

Comment: @Cody Gray (When you edit, make sure to add the phrase in objective c 6 or 8 more times, just to be super-duper clear.) Sarcastic, and unnecessary

Comment: @Cody Gray Really? You think this is a real question? sarcastic and unnecessary

Comment: @James: Expressing disbelief is "sarcastic and unnecessary"? How would you have written that? "I don't understand how you can think this is a real question?" Would that have been better?

Comment: @Cody Gray I think there are better ways to point out the illegitimacy of the question than calling out the asker.  I would have pointed to the obvious grammar and content issues and left it at that.  This commentary comes off as rude to me.

Comment: I think more sarcasm would probably be appropriate. The OP said *"The question was closed without comment shortly after it was posted, despite being fairly clear..."* when as pointed out, it was most definitely not clear - in fact it was terrible. In this case, a rescue edit has saved the question. So this is a good example of an edit resulting in reopen but it is in no way an abuse of "not a real question" and Caleb (14k+) should surely have known that. Bringing up the issue as an abuse of the system rather than as a request for reopen votes deserves some mock disbelief - `in objective c`.

Comment: @theChrisKent: I do sometimes wonder how people who seem unable to write a complete sentence expect to be able to write syntactically valid code. Nevertheless, I think we do try to make allowances for people who may not be able to express themselves clearly in English. The intent of the question seemed quite clear to me, possibly because it's a common newbie question about Objective-C, so closing as not a real question without comment did seem inappropriate. I didn't understand, and that's why I asked. I'm not sure I need to be mocked for it, but I do appreciate the answers.

Comment: @Caleb: I wasn't intending to mock you, just to be clear. As I mentioned earlier, I was honestly shocked that you considered this to be a real question. But sometimes knowledgeable people in the field can extract meaning where there appears to be none. And that's exactly what the "edit" button is for, just as you've done here.

Comment: @CodyGray, I'm fine and I sure don't mind a little ribbing. Your explanation was helpful -- thanks for that -- and I think it led to the right outcome. I disagree with theChrisKent's assertion that *more* sarcasm would be appropriate, though. ;-) For what it's worth, I'm fine with "no" and some explanation as an answer to my question about abuse, and that's what you provided. Cheers.

Comment: @Caleb I was irritated at James' assertion that Cody was being rude when I agreed with Cody's answer and reasoning. I also was not wanting to mock you nor was I encouraging Cody to do so. I meant mock disbelief as in sarcastic questioning (Pretend disbelief or exaggerated shock) as in "Really?". I think your saving of the question is great and I also strongly disagree with voting down questions struggling with English. This particular question could only be saved by an expert so I don't think the close votes were abusive. Fortunately experts like you can edit and then ask to reopen.

Comment: I should've just rolled my eye's at Jame's attempt to justify his lame joke instead of inserting myself (with my own lame joke to boot). But I'm a bit of an idiot. So hugs and kisses all around! I'll butt out, but for the record, I'm always up for more sarcasm.

Comment: @theChrisKent, it's all good. ;-)